# problem while displaying image in imageview

Tags: iphone

i create a view based project named myclass.

and i add another UIviewcontroller subclass to it, named as webdata.

In the webdataviewcontroller.m i get image from the webserver.

I need to display this image on imageview in myclassViewController.m from webdataViewController.m

for this my code in  webdataViewController.m is

```
docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    imagepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image.png",docDir];
    logopath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/logo.png",docDir];

myclassViewController *obj = [[myclassViewController alloc]init];
obj.homeimage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagepath];
```

but image is not displayed,i try to print image in console

```
NSLog(@"image to display %@",obj.homeimage.image);
NSLog(@"image to display %@",[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagepath]);
```

but i get like this

```
image to display (null)
 image to display <UIImage: 0x6f614b0>
```

why i get null for obj.homeimage.image,i did n't get can any one please help me.

Thank u in adavance.

(Let me add comment if question is not understandable)

Comment: You should use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` to create paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that obj.homeimage is not nil? If it is nil then obj.homeimage.image = ... will result to setting image property to nil object, that is "nothing".

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you give us the code for `myclassViewController` ?

Also you have a lot of mistakes in capitalization, etc. It makes it hard to read your code and it's messy.

`myClassViewController` should be `MyClassViewController`
`webdataViewController` should be `WebDataViewController`

You should camel case variable names
`homeimage` should be `homeImage` 
`imagepath` should be `imagePath`

You said you *subclassed* myclassViewController, I think by that you meant you added it as a *subview*. If so when you execute the code:

```
myclassViewController *obj = [[myclassViewController alloc]init];
```

you are creating a NEW myclassViewController, not referencing the parent view controller. You need a pointer to the the instance of the `myclassViewController` that added `webdataViewController` as a subview, and add the image to it's property. Also I'm guessing here lies your problem, you are creating a new empty instance of `myclassViewController` therefore you have not initialized your ivars. (Unless you did so in your `-init` method, but I would doubt that). So you `alloc`-ed and `init`-ed a new `myclassViewController` but none of it's variables are initialized so you are just messaging nil objects probably. Which is why your code isn't crashing yet still not responding. Once again this is a guess, but it probably is the problem.

I can edit with more information if you give the code for myclassViewController.